# Differences between A Statistician and a Data Analyst In Industry

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

What is the Difference in the job of a Statistician and a Data Analyst In Industry?
My take is that although both analyse data, a Statistician deals with the more theoretical aspects of data such as using mathematics to analyse data and to create mathematical models of data. So their work is more towards the mathematics side of things. Whereas the job of a Data Analyst deals more with the programming and side of things and their job is more practical in nature and they focus more on the implementation side.

Im more of a theoretical person and im more mathematically orientated and i wanted to do a job that involves lots of math, so is a statistician job more suited  for me rather than a Data Analyst?

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely to be.  Find out all you can about the actual duties of a job.  If possible, ask those already occupying such positions with that employer.  They'll often give you more accurate accounts of the breakdown of duties than the hiring manager will.  Be prepared for such duties to include much more than modeling and math:  potentially data management, programming, literature searches, program or business operation, drafting articles or memos or grant proposals, marketing, business development, management, or other functions.

Comment: Can only second that. E.g. "statistician" could also be very focussed on doing analyses/programming things that other people have specified/worked out. "Data analyst" has even more meanings that I've seen - anything from someone looking after a database to a programmer creating dashboards for managers, or what many people would call a "statistician", or what many people might call a "data scientist" type of role. Companies come up with weird job title conventions and it can be hard to guess what they mean